# I've broken my rails installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Got a new machine and ported settings and files over. Went to update to Rails 3.2 and now I'm getting a list of installed gems when I run "gem list" but when I run the rails command, it tells me: Rails isn't installed.

I'm running OS X Lion and Rails 3.2. I've tried editing the path and creating a symlink and nothing seems to work. I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: have you tried calling rails absolute path?

Comment: I don't think I know how to do that. Any guidance?

Comment: /usr/bin/rails is the absolute path to rails on my OSX Lion install

Comment: where would i put that or how would i check that?

Comment: Open Terminal.  Then copy and paste that in, if it says file not found then rails is either in a different location or it's not installed

Comment: output: Rails is not currently installed on this system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial and install Ruby Version Manager.  It's got all the steps I followed to get ruby working on my mac.

http://seanbehan.com/mac-os-x/installing-and-using-rvm-on-mac-os-x-creating-gemsets-and-reverting-to-original-environment/